# Server - Browser showes site only after server is terminated

Tags: c, sockets, http, tcp

I am trying to programm a small HTTP-Server with fork(). When I connect to it via firefox, it doesn't show the the page, until I terminate the Server.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define LISTEN_MAX 5
#define CONT_MAX 10000
#define PORT 8081
#define MAX_FILE 2
#define S_SHORT 50
#define MAX_CONTENT 1000
#define MAX_HEADER 200
const size_t BUF_LEN = 1024; //was 128
const size_t REQUEST_LEN=1024;
char file_names[MAX_FILE][S_SHORT];
FILE *file_deskriptors[MAX_FILE];
int file_sizes[MAX_FILE];
char file_contents[MAX_FILE][MAX_CONTENT];

// Something unexpected happened. Report error and terminate.
void sysErr( char *msg, int exitCode ) {
    fprintf( stderr, "%s\n\t%s\n", msg, strerror( errno ) );
    exit( exitCode );
}

// get_line was borrowed from Tiny HTTPd under GPLv2
// https://sourceforge.net/projects/tinyhttpd/?source=typ_redirect
int get_line(int sock, char *buf, int size) {
    int i = 0;
    char c = '\0';
    int n;

    while ((i < size - 1) && (c != '\n'))
    {
        n = recv(sock, &c, 1, 0);
        /* DEBUG printf("%02X\n", c); */
        if (n > 0)
        {
            if (c == '\r')
            {
                n = recv(sock, &c, 1, MSG_PEEK);
                /* DEBUG printf("%02X\n", c); */

                if ((n > 0) && (c == '\n'))
                    recv(sock, &c, 1, 0);
                else
                    c = '\n';
            }
            buf[i] = c;
            i++;
        }
        else
            c = '\n';
    }
    buf[i] = '\0';
    return(i);
}

void copyHeaderToBuffer(char *tx_buff, int *status) {
    switch(*status) {
        case 200: strcpy(tx_buff,"HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContentÂ­type: text/html\r\n\r\n"); break;

    }
    return;
}

void answer(int *accfd, char *request ) {
    int file_size, file_index, status, sent_bytes;
    file_size, file_index, status = 0;
    char method[S_SHORT], ressource[S_SHORT], proto[S_SHORT];
    char tx_buff[MAX_CONTENT+MAX_HEADER];

    //rehash query
    splitRequest(request, method, ressource, proto);

    //check for <GET>
    checkMethod(method);

    //search the file and get index
    getFileIndexByName(ressource, &file_index);

    file_size = file_sizes[file_index];

    status = getFileStatus(&file_index);

    createAnswerMessage(tx_buff, &status, &file_index);

    //send the answer
    if ( (sent_bytes= write( accfd, tx_buff, strlen(tx_buff))) ==  -1 ) {
    sysErr( "[-] Client Fault: SEND", -4 );
    }

    return;
}

void createAnswerMessage(char *tx_buff, int *status, int *file_index) {
    copyHeaderToBuffer(tx_buff, status);
    strcat(tx_buff,file_contents[*file_index]);
    strcat(tx_buff,"\r\n");
    return;
}

int getFileStatus(int *file_index) {
    return 200;
}

void splitRequest(char *request, char *method, char *ressource, char *proto) {
    char *temp;
    if ((temp = strtok(request, " ")) != NULL) {
        strcpy(method, temp);
    }

    if ((temp = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL) {
        strcpy(ressource, temp);
    }

    if ((temp = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL) {
        strcpy(proto, temp);
    }
    //remove leading "/" from ressource
    cleanRessource(ressource);
    return;
}

void cleanRessource(char *ressource) {
    if (*ressource == '/') {
    printf("\nstr_len_ressource: %i",strlen(ressource));
    for ( int i=0; i < strlen(ressource); i++ ) {
        ressource[i]=ressource[i+1];
        }
    }
    return;
}

void checkMethod(char *method){
    if (strcmp(method, "GET") ) {
        printf("\n[-] Error: Method \"%s\" not known .",method);
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("\nincheckMethod method = %s",method);
    return;
}

void getFileIndexByName (char *ressource, int *file_index) {
    for (int i=0; i<MAX_FILE; i++) {
        if ( !strcmp(ressource, file_names[i]) ) {
            *file_index = i;
            return;
        }
    }
    printf("\[-] Error: File \"%s\" not known.",ressource);
    exit(0);
}

void filesInit () {
    memset(file_names, '\0', sizeof(file_names));
    memset(file_contents, '\0', sizeof(file_contents));
    //define your files here:
    strcpy(file_names[0],"index.htm");
    for (int i=0; i<MAX_FILE; i++) {
        //choose only existing files
        if (file_names[i][0]!='\0') {
            //open file
            file_deskriptors[i] = fopen(file_names[i],"r");
            //get file size
            fseek(file_deskriptors[i], 0, SEEK_END);
            file_sizes[i] = ftell(file_deskriptors[i]);
            //read the file content to file_contents
            fseek(file_deskriptors[i], 0, SEEK_SET);
            fread(file_contents[i], 1, CONT_MAX, file_deskriptors[i]);
        }
    }
    return;
}

void filesClose() {
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //kill childs if recieving SIGCHLD
    signal(SIGCHLD,SIG_IGN);
    int connfd, accfd;

    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
    socklen_t sockaddr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    //initial the available files on server
    filesInit();
    // create socket
    if ( ( connfd = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 ) ) < 0) {
        sysErr( "Server Fault : SOCKET", -1 );
    }
    // Set params so that we receive IPv4 packets from anyone on the specified port
    memset( &server_addr, 0, sockaddr_len );
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server_addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port        = htons( PORT );

    //bind socket to port
    if ( bind( connfd, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sockaddr_len ) < 0 ) {
        sysErr( "\n[-] Server Fault : BIND", -2 );
    }else{printf("[+] SERVER ONLINE");}

    //let server listen for incoming connections
    if ( listen( connfd, LISTEN_MAX) < 0 ) {
            sysErr( "[-] Server Fault : LISTEN", -3 );
    }

    //main loop for accepting clients
    while ( true ) {
        pid_t pid;
        //connecting specific client
        if ( (accfd=accept( connfd, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &sockaddr_len )) < 0 ) {
        sysErr( "[-] Server Fault : ACCEPT", -4 );
        }
        //fork & answer
        else {
        printf("\n[+] CLIENT CONNECTED\n");
        switch ( pid = fork() ) {
        case -1:    {
                    printf("\n[-] Error while fork()");
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                    }
        case 0:     {
                    int req_line_len=1;         //length of request line
                    int first_line_on = 1;      //set first line parameter
                    char req_line[S_SHORT];     //current read line
                    char first_line[S_SHORT];   //save first line

                    memset(req_line, 0, S_SHORT);
                    memset(first_line, 0, S_SHORT);

                    printf("\n[+] HTTP REQUEST on accfd: %i",accfd);
                    //reading line by line from socket
                    while((req_line_len > 0) && strcmp("\n", req_line)){
                        req_line_len = get_line( accfd, req_line, S_SHORT-1);
                        //get first line and save it
                        if (first_line_on) { first_line_on = 0; strcpy(first_line,req_line); }
                        if((req_line_len > 0) && strcmp("\n", req_line)) printf("%s",req_line);
                    }
                    //answering to client
                    answer(accfd, first_line);
                    //close connection
                    if (!close(accfd)) {printf("\n[+] CONNECTION CLOSED");}
                    exit(0);
                    break;
                    }
        default:    {
                    //main process
                    break;
                    }
        }
    }
}
//close listening socket
close( connfd );
//close server files
filesClose();
return 0;
}
```

The child is terminated, and I get the answer CONNECTION CLOSED

Is there a logical mistake in my Code?

EDIT:

I added a full minimum code. 
The "\r\n" I add at to the transmitting msg. 
It works fine if I add

```
close(accfd);
```

to the main(), but I think it is not actually the problem(only a side effect solution)

the index.htm could be:

```
<html><body><b>index</b><br>C is a interesting language!</body></html>
```

Comment: Do you have the required `\n` terminating characters?

Comment: @Tibrogargan: `\r\n`

Comment: The server most likely sends an incomplete set of data to the client. So the client waits for the missing stuff before starting to render what it got. The moment the connections goes down the client realises that there is nothing more to come, stops waiting and tries rendering what it got. The bug might be in `createAnswerMessage`.

Comment: This `void answer(int *accfd, ...` should be `void answer(int accfd, ...`. Socket descriptors are of type `int`, not a pointer to `int`, what `int*` is.

Comment: All in all the question cannot be answered based on the code you show. Cut his down to a minimal working example.

Comment: @ alk 

    \r\n

is there, the minimum working example is posted above.

Answer (score -1):

When you call fork() the file descriptors of the parent in copied to the child, this is why you can still access the socket in the child process. The network stack will keep the socket alive as long as you have at least one file descriptor open to the socket. You close the socket in the child process but still have it open in the parent.

In other words adding a call to `close(accfd)` in the parent should fix your problem.

Comment: I strongly doubt leaving the socket open is the cause. The client is expected to render the result the moment, the message received is complete, no matter whether the underlying socket connection had been closed or not. Sure closing it will have the same result as ending the server, but still ...

Comment: Yes, it works but I think it doesn't solve the actual problem.